# Frequency-to-Voltage convertor diagram questions

Tags: transistors, audio, frequency, converter

I'm relatively new to electronics, but I'm interested in making the Frequency-to-Voltage convertor linked [here](http://mathscinotes.com/2014/03/a-simple-frequency-to-voltage-converter/) as part of a larger project linked [here](https://github.com/DevonCrawford/LED-Music-Visualizer).

Here is a diagram of the circuit I want to make:

[image: LTspice schematic diagram]

([Image source: Math Encounters Blog](http://mathscinotes.com/2014/03/a-simple-frequency-to-voltage-converter/))

Whilst the diagram seems clear enough for me in most places, there were a few things that I would really appreciate if someone could clarify for me:

1. What is the `.tran 10` transistor referred to at the bottom of the diagram?
2. In the ["Larger Project" I linked above](https://github.com/DevonCrawford/LED-Music-Visualizer), I assume that the positive and negative of the audio signal would go correspondingly to the positive and negative of the "Sensor Interface Output" part of the diagram; is this correct?
3. I assume that the "Supply Voltage" is, as it hints, a constant voltage needed to supply the circuit. If so, what would this voltage be? 5V? 3.3V?

I would be very grateful if someone could give me some guidance regarding the 3 questions I posed above, as I am new to this sort of electronics.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: .tran 10 is a SPICE directive telling it to do a _transient_ simulation for 10 seconds. The supply voltage is exactly what it's labelled on the schematic, 12 volts.

Comment: @Felthry Thanks for your reply! I apologise, I didn't see the `12` on the diagram! I'm still rather confused about the `.tran 10` though; is it another component I would need or what?

Comment: Like I said, it's a SPICE directive. It's telling the simulator what to do.

Comment: @Felthry Just to confirm, the `.tran 10` is purely for software testing and is nothing that would need any action in real life. I.e. for simulating the frequency in the circuit and therefore is just left over so can be ignored?

Comment: Yes. It's instructions for the simulator only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- The diagram you used was drawn in a simulation software. You need to specify a ground reference node in most simulation softwares, that means that you need to tell the software which node has zero potential or voltage. the triangle you see at the bottom of the diagram shows that the node it is connected to has zero potential. It is not a transistor or any other component. .tran 10 as Felthry said in the comments is a way of telling the software to perform simulation for 10 seconds. you don't need to worry about that niether.

2- Basically when the sonsors output is greater than 12.7 volts the diode and transistor conduct and output voltage gradually goes up to 12v. when the sensors output is lower than that the transistor turns off and the capacitor in the output starts discharging gradually to zero. I guess the gradual rate of the changing output plays an important role in this application. This rate is determined by the values of the resistor and the capacitor in the output. I'm not sure what you are asking but I hope this answer helps you understand what happens in the circuit and figure it out by yourself.

3- I believe you got that, its 12v.